# jenkins hook up with apache sites-enabled

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to hook in jenkins into my currently configured site.

My current site is located at `/var/www/aaronlote.com/checkout/` - jenkins is building into `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/aaronlote.com/`

If I update my vhost to point to `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/aaronlote.com/` I get a 403 error, the directory is unreadable.

So I tried adding this as a build script in side the job:

```
rm -rf /var/www/aaronlote.com/checkout/
cp /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/aaronlote.com/ /var/www/aaronlote.com/checkout/
```

This runs but I have permission errors, e.g.

```
rm: cannot remove `/var/www/aaronlote.com/checkout/public/js/router.js': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/var/www/aaronlote.com/checkout/public/js/main.js': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove `/var/www/aaronlote.com/checkout/public/js/text.js': Permission denied
```

I then looked as using `sudo su` inside the jobs build but got errors and didn't think it was a great idea having jenkins running super user commands.

Am I doing something obviously wrong or is there a way to get around this current set up issue I have?

Comment: Try changing the permissions of `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/aaronlote.com/` so that `jenkins` is the user (I'm assuming Jenkins is running under the `jenkins` user name) and `www-data` as the group (or whatever Apache is running under).

Comment: I've fixed this by removing the bash completely and making /var/www/aaronlote.com/checkout a symbolic link to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/aaronlote.com/